# JQuery : Iterating between start and end elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have below **HTML**

```
<div class="parent">
    <span class="child">1</span>
    <span class="child">2</span>
    <span class="child">3</span>
    <span class="child">4</span>
    <span class="child">5</span>
</div>
```

and below **CSS**

```
.parent .child {
    border : 1px solid black;
    display :inline-block;
    width:40px;
    height:25px;
    text-align:center;
    cursor:pointer;
}
.mark {
    background-color: green;
}
```

and simple click event for to see selected element a below.

```
$(".parent > .child").click(function(e){
    if(e.shiftKey) {
        $(".parent .child").each(function(){
            $(this).addClass("mark");
        });
    }
    else {
        $(this).addClass("mark");
    }
});
```

**Edited :** When I click one element and another element with shiftKey , between these two elements should be add class `mark`. But my code iterate all elements as `$(".parent > .child")....` I would like to avoid it (I mean if 2 elements between them , I would like to iterate 4 times *(inclusive start and element) with my iteration)*.

My question is can I iterate between two selected elements (inclusive) instead of iterating from thier parent element *(in my case I don't want to iterate from `parent`)* ? I know the start and end elements. If so, why I need to iterate all elements and check their status as I want ? [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/64582aqt/3/) link.

**For clear question ...**

I have 10 HTML element ,assume 3 is start and 6 is end.I would like to iterate as

```
(for var i=3 ; i <=6 ; i++) {...}
```

instead of iterating all elements and check their status as

```
(for var i=1 ; i <=10 ; i++) {
 // checking is it between start and end elements
}
```

Comment: sorry... not clear what you are trying to do

Comment: which is the start and end elements

Comment: sorry , when I click first element , please assume this is first element and next click element may second. I would like to iterate between these two elements.

Comment: then add the class mark to all elements between the start and end

Comment: @ArunPJohny I mean I would like to iterate between two elements these have 'mark' class.

Comment: like https://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/64582aqt/9/ ?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/rejithrkrishnan/64582aqt/12/ try this. I've posted an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/rejithrkrishnan/64582aqt/12/)

Try this demo. Not sure if it accomplishes what you need. Comment if changes needed.

```
$(".parent .child").click(function () {
    if($(".parent .child.mark:first").length == 1 && !$(this).hasClass('mark')){
        firstIndex = $(".parent .child.mark:first").index();
        thisIndex = $(this).index();
        start = Math.min(thisIndex, firstIndex);
        end = Math.max(firstIndex, thisIndex) + 1;
        $('.parent .child').slice(start, end).each(function(){
            $(this).addClass('mark');
        })
    } else {
        $(this).addClass('mark');
    }
});
```

Comment: Arrrr... OMG .. This is what I want , no no no not anymore. This is complete answer for me. Thanks alot for helping me. :)

Answer (score 0):

Not clear from your question but are you saying something [like this](https://jsfiddle.net/Bhagya/cj9b8jr1/)

Jquery for next element is :

```
$(".parent .child").click(function(){
    $(this).addClass("mark");
    $(this).next().addClass('mark');
    if($(this).is(':last-child')){
        $('.parent .child:first-child').addClass('mark');
    }
});
```

If element is last child then have added class mark to first ,this one was my assumption so far.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use this:

$( ".mark" ).nextUntil( ".mark" ).css( "color", "red" );

$( ".mark" )--> this is your first click item
.nextUntil( ".mark" )--> this one is your second click

Hope it will works